# Does python have an "error" module?

Tags: python

does python have error module? when i wrote 'import error' in python 2.7.6, it returns "No module named error.' but 'import error' is a part of program in a textbook？should i doult something in the textbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a custom module. The python standard library does not have an error module.

Maybe you missed something in the textbook where an error module was created.